# Script required

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose we have a table #temp1, what we required here is, we want an additional column **ABC** and in that, we want to print the output as *(10-10 = 0), (20-10) = 10, (30-10 = 20), (40-10 = 30) and (50-10 = 40)*

So, we have created a table and insert script below.

```
Create table #temp1 (ID Int Identity(1,1),Name varchar(10),Series bigint)

insert into #temp1 values('A',10)
insert into #temp1 values('B',20)
insert into #temp1 values('C',30)
insert into #temp1 values('D',40)
insert into #temp1 values('E',50)
```

I tried as below, where its incrementing the values rows by rows.

```
select ID,Name,Series, SUM(series) over(order by series asc Rows Between Unbounded Preceding and Current Row) ranking from #temp1
```

Output should be:

```
ID|Name|Series|ABC
1 |  A |  10  | 0
2 |  B |  20  | 10
3 |  C |  30  | 20
4 |  D |  40  | 30
5 |  E |  50  | 40
```

Can anyone here me, how to do that.

Comment: I think it's simply `Series - 10`

Comment: you're not using SQL Server 2008 with a sample query using `Rows Between Unbounded Preceding`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below query

```
select ID,Name,Series,(series - (select top 1 series from #temp1)) as abc from #temp1
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simply `Series - 10`:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Series, Series - 10 AS ABC
FROM #Temp1;
```

Comment: We can't just hardcode the value. not even use any variable to store the value.

Comment: @Madhur That was not in your question, so I answer as you ask and with simply way :)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Sami. Unless something else is intended from the query that was attempted, it seems like it should not be Series - 10, but rather series - the first series value in the table?

If that is the case, then the answer should be

```
select ID,Name,Series, Series - MIN(series) over 
(order by series asc Rows Between unbounded Preceding and Current Row) ABC from #temp1
```

Answer (score 0):

select ID,Name,Series,(series - 10) as abc from #temp1

Comment: Please consider an explanation of what the code does.